# Bot framework continueDialog not popping off the stack

Tags: node.js, botframework

I create chatbot by Bot Framework and use LINE API Developers on ***node.js***

> Problem on my work was `continueDialog` not continue waterfallDialog next step. 
>   and the stack didn't change when it's done with continueDialog

**before `continueDialog`**

`stack1 [ { id: 'xxxDialog',
    state: { options: {}, values: [Object], stepIndex: 0 } } ]`

**after `continueDialog`**

`stack2 [ { id: 'xxxDialog',
    state: { options: {}, values: [Object], stepIndex: 0 } } ]`

on index.js

```
server.post('/api/line',jsonParser, async (req, res)=> {
  const conversationReference = { 
          type: "message", 
          text: "Hello world" ,
          channelData: { clientActivityID: "id-xxxx" },
          channelId: 'api/line/id-xxxx',
          recipient:
            { id: lineID`,
              name: 'line',
              role: 'botLine' },
              serviceUrl: 'https://localhost:3978' ,
          from:
            { id: lineId`,
              name: 'User',
              role: 'user' },
          conversation: { id: lineId },
       };
  const context = await adapter.createContext(conversationReference);

  await bot.onTurn(context);
});
```

on bot.js

```
class Bot extends ActivityHandler {
     /**
     *
     * @param {ConversationState} conversationState
     * @param {UserState} userState
     * @param {Dialog} dialog
     */
    constructor(conversationState, userState) {    
        super();
        this.conversationState = conversationState;
        this.userState = userState;

        this.dialogStateAccessor = conversationState.createProperty('dialogStateAccessor');
        this.dialogAccessor= conversationState.createProperty('testAccessor');

        this.dialog = new DialogSet(this.dialogStateAccessor);

        this.dialog.add(new WaterfallDialog('testDialog', [
            this.step1.bind(this), 
            this.step2.bind(this)


    ]));
}

 async step1(stepContext){
    linesent("step 1") ;
    return {status : DialogTurnStatus.waiting} ;
}
async step2(stepContext){
    linesent("step 2") ;
        return await stepContext.endDialog(); 
}

 async onTurn(turnContext) {
 const reservation = await this.dialogAccessor.get(turnContext, null);   
        // Generate a dialog context for our dialog set.
        const dc = await this.dialog.createContext(turnContext);
  if (!dc.activeDialog){
      // If there is no active dialog, check whether we have a reservation yet.
      if (!reservation) {
          // If not, start the dialog.
          await dc.beginDialog(`testDialog`);
      }
}
 else {
  //Continue the dialog.
  const dialogTurnResult = await dc.continueDialog();
 }
return await this.conversationState.saveChanges(turnContext, false);
}
```

but it did not show any error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: get it !!
just changed continueDialog to resumeDialog on your activeDialog the waterfall will working on next step.

Comment: Glad that you could resolve the issue. Just for clarity, a continueDialog continues execution of the active multi-turn dialog, if there is one.ResumeDialog is to support nesting of dialogs (where a dialog has child dialog). When a child Dialog completes, the ResumeDialog on the parent dialog will be called. Refer to https://www.brightdevelopers.com/overview-of-dialogs-for-bot-framework-v4/ for more clarity

Comment: Also, you can post your resolution in the answer so that it helps others.

Comment: @ranusharao thas's really help,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the continueDialog method be

```
 async continueDialog(dc) {
        // Don't do anything for non-message activities
        if (dc.context.activity.type !== botbuilder_core_1.ActivityTypes.Message) {
            return dialog_1.Dialog.EndOfTurn;
        }
        // Run next step with the message text as the result.
        return await this.resumeDialog(dc, dialog_1.DialogReason.continueCalled, dc.context.activity.text);
    }
```

the bot always do `if` condition.

Changed `continueDialog`  to `resumeDialog` on your activeDialog id the waterfall will working on next step.